# Port WebGL project to standalone app

Tags: windows, cross-platform, webgl

For school I have to make a program that works on two platform, I'm thinking to use WebGL and just windows.
Now I was wondering if it's possible to make a WebGL application and then port it to windows without too much effort :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one if you create a WebGL program then it works in Windows/Mac/Linux automatically, so there's little need to "port" it.

Assuming that, this being a school assignment, the idea is that you must code it twice however, that would be an interesting platform to go after. There's a couple of things to think about before jumping into it, though:

- Have you done any Windows development before? Because it can be a nasty shock to the system if you haven't.
- What language are you intending to use? OpenGL was designed to be used with the Win32 C API, but there are wrappers available for .Net if you're more comfortable there, but you'll find less in the way of tutorials/documentation.
- When is your assignment due? If you're learning a whole new API and only have a day or two to do it, you may want to reconsider platforms.

The bits that are going to differ the most between WebGL and desktop OpenGL are the window, input, and file management. If those aren't intimidating to you then you should be fine. A useful resource in this case would be the NeHe and LearningWebGL tutorials.

The [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) are a set of popular (and fairly old, not really the best written) OpenGL tutorials that have been ported to cover a wide variety of platforms but were written for Win32 initially.

The [LearningWebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/) tutorials are basically just a WebGL-centric version of the NeHe tutorials, so you can immediately see some of the parallels between the two, and hopefully that will get you up an running faster.

Whatever route you go, good luck!

Comment: Well, the idea is that I indeed have to code it twice, but also that it takes a little time as possible to do it the second time (by reusing code, ...). I'm also in a game development school, but programmed mainly in c++ and c#. Of course being a programmer I want to do as little work as possible to get it working :P Oh yes, it has to be done for my xmass exams, so there a little more time than 2days (I do have a lot of other homework though). Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, I was just wondering if it is hard to do this. But you think this is very possible? The project I have in mind isn't very large, but being able to reuse code would of course be awesome.

Comment: It's perfectly doable, especially if you have C++ and C# experience. I'll warn you, though, that your code reuse between WebGL and a C++ app is going to be pretty minimal. You'll be able to reuse some shaders and your 3D resources, but that's about it. If the assignment is specifically looking for code reuse then you may want to consider other options. (C++ vs. .Net may actually be a pretty good one under that criteria)